# Gene frequency — database/site

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, population-genetics, gene

Is there any free database when one can check the gene frequency in a healthy population? For example I would like to check it for genes like BIN1, CLU or CR1. On the English Wikipedia I found a gene frequency for APOE gene (for example: 79% for e4 and 7% for e2), and it was linked to the specific publication. I wonder if one need to look for specific publication when looking for information like that or there is any database with such information available?

Comment: I believe SNPedia has frequency information, but I don't know the breadth of their database. Not a biologist.

Comment: @MelanieShebel Thanks a lot, gonna check that!

Comment: @Mary Are you talking about a specific species?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some, but not all, gene frequencies in a range of populations at [The Allele Frequency Net Database - Allele, haplotype and genotype frequencies in Worldwide Populations](http://allelefrequencies.net/).

However, your question is broad genes have a lot of variation within them, the most basic being [Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms (SNPs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism) and you've already been pointed to one source of information ([SNPedia](https://www.snpedia.com/) which is new to me) but you can look at the variation of allele frequency of SNPs in different populations by looking at [dbSNP](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp)<sup>1</sup>.  Note they have a subset for variation associated with clinical phenotypes.

---

<sup>1</sup> This may be the source on which at least some of SNPedia is based as dbSNP has been around for a very long time.